# C# How to debug Control.DoDragDrop Method

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, null

I'm reading a foreign source code and there occurs sometimes a

```
NullException
```

by **Drag'n'Drop** operation. The problem is, that all parameters **are never** null, so I'd like **to be able to debug this method** somehow.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any exception thrown while a drag+drop is in progress is swallowed by a catch all handler in DoDragDrop.  You can see the first-chance exception in the Output window but that's all.  To get the debugger to stop use Debug + Exceptions, tick the Thrown checkbox on CLR exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

OK !

It seems that the Call Stack in Message Details helps to locate the problem.
Anyways.. for me it's sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround (to debug drag and drop methods)

1. Start VS in Administrator mode
2. Start your exe in a cmd Windows (not Administrator) or with explorer (not Run as Administrator)
3. Attach (in VS your exe)
   ...
   This works fine with Visual Studio Community 2022 17.8.2.